# Android store API Keys in secret

Tags: android, github

I have an Android app public on the Github. Even if it is public I have some values like API keys that I don't want other people to see.

I've seen people storing them on `gradle.properties` but I have that file visible also.

I've see that the `gitignore` command will not commit that file at all in case I update it.

**Question:** Which is the best way to achieve this for Android projects and keep the project public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file called `local.properties` at the project root level which could be used to hold the api keys. It shouldn't be committed to source control.

Comment: and if i pull from master in another branch? Will i also have my API keys there?

Comment: @stavroXhardha, assuming it's not in source control, changing branches or pulling from another branch would not affect the contents of the local.properties file.

Comment: well I need a way to somehow edit/commit/push this file but only what I can see it publicly.